# javascript array index test

Tags: javascript

if I have an array `myArray` which I am looping through:

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
   if(myArray[i] == myArray[i+1])
      //do something
}
```

Clearly, `myArray[i+1]` will fail on the last iteration.  Short of testing if `i == (myArray.length - 1)`, is there a clean way to not fail on that if statement and just have it evaluate to false (if `myArray[i+1]` is out of bounds)?

Comment: Oh, and I know I'm probably better off keeping a variable pointing to the previous value and in each iteration just testing if the current value is equal to that stored previous value.  But I'd still like to know how to do it as shown in the question.

Comment: *"Clearly, myArray[i+1] will fail on the last iteration."* Well, yes and no, depends what you mean by "fail". It won't throw an exception, but it's almost certainly not what you want. It will compare `myArray[i]` with `undefined`. Regardless, best to stop earlier, as shown in KennyTM's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just iterate up to the (N-2)th item?

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length-1;i++) {
  ...
```

---

if you must iterate till the end, the only way to work in general is to explicitly check if the index is valid. Either

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++ i)
  if (i+1 != myArray.length) {
    ...
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++ i)
  if (!(i+1 in myArray)) {
    ...
```

However, if you can ensure all items in the array cannot be `undefined` or `null`, then your original code already works because an index out-of-bound will return `undefined`, and `undefined == x` will be false unless `x` is also `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: well I feel dumb now.  yea that would definitely work.  still is there a graceful way in javascript to have an out of bounds array pointer evaluate to false instead of throwing an error?

Comment: ...because actually the way my logic is setup (and I'm not saying it can't be refactored) I still need to get to that last iteration (N-1)th item.

Comment: Actually `myArray[i+1]` wouldn't fail with an error. It would simply return `undefined`, which compared to `myArray[i]` which would return `false` (unless of course `myArray[i]` is also `undefined`) and everything would be ok.

Comment: interesting.  so, since contractually the array should never have underfined or null, it wouldn't be poor code to leave it as is then, i guess..even though coming from a Java background it looks dangerous

Comment: As T.J. Crowder said above, `myArray[myArray.length]` will evaluate to `undefined`, which is a falsy value. It shouldn't throw an error unless you're then trying to access a property of that array element.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jquery source for some inspiration: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3a0a35288304ab5289a1/src/core.js#L632